# Flutter GoRouter App Schema Deeplink different format

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I'm encountering an issue with the GoRouter in my Flutter application while attempting to invoke different routes using a specific deeplink format:

```
appschema://a
```

This deeplink format is not working. It will open the app, however I get the following error screen:

```
GoException: no routes for location: /
```

In a native iOS application I am used to use that format and it works fine. If I call the deeplink with only one slash, the app opens and navigates to the correct screen.

```
appschema:/a
```

Below is the relevant part of my GoRouter implementation:

```
final _router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  initialLocation: "/a",
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
        return MainTabBarScreen(child: child);
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/a',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return FirstScreen();
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              path: 'details',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return FirstDetailScreen();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/b',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return SecondScreen(articleId: 3);
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              path: 'details2',
              parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return SecondScreen(articleId: 4);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
);
```

Despite following this structure, the double slash in the original deeplink seems to be causing issues. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just a dumb question without actually looking into this but have you tried adding another route with path '//a'? Might be able to do a redirect if that's the case.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Yes, I tried that. It didn't work for me.